# Initialising a struct that contains a vector of itself

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, initializer-list, incomplete-type

I have a menu system that I want to initialise from constant data. A `MenuItem` can contain, as a sub-menu, a vector of `MenuItems`. But it only works up to a point. Here are the bare bones of the problem:

```
#include <vector>
struct S { std::vector<S> v ; } ;

S s1 = { } ;
S s2 = { { } } ;
S s3 = { { { } } } ;
```

`g++ -std=c++0x` (version 4.4.5) copes with `s1` and `s2`, but `s3` comes back with:

```
prog.cpp:6:22: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

(see [ideone](http://ideone.com/rDThI)). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's undefined behavior to have an incomplete type as a template argument to a standard library container.

Comment: For more information, see Matt Austern's ["The Standard Librarian: Containers of Incomplete Types"](http://drdobbs.com/184403814)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GMan is correct in his comment:  in the declaration of `S::v` in your code, `S` is still incomplete.  A type must be complete to be usable as the value type in an STL container.  For more information see Matt Austern's article ["The Standard Librarian: Containers of Incomplete Types."](http://drdobbs.com/184403814)

If you were to switch to a container that is usable with an incomplete type, then your code is fine.  For example, given the following:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
struct Container
{
    Container() { }
    Container(std::initializer_list<T>) { }
};

struct S { Container<S> v; };
```

then your original initialization should work fine:

```
S s3 = { { { } } } ;
```

This would work too:

```
S s4 = { { { { { { { { { { { { { { { { /*zomg*/ } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } };
```

Comment: Isn't this oversimplified to the point of absurdity? That isn't "a struct that contains a vector of itself", and you've not 'switched to a container that allows an incomplete type'... because neither of them contain any data! This code stores nothing and does nothing. Which, it seems to me, neatly parallels the impossibility of 'an object that contains itself' by value.

Answer (score 6):

boost::optional and boost::recursive_wrapper look useful for this

```
struct S { // one brace
    boost::optional< // another brace
      boost::recursive_wrapper< // another brace
        std::vector< // another brace
          S
        >
      >
    > v; 
};
```

You need 4 braces for every submenu you add. Brace elision does not happen when constructor calls are involved. For example

```
S m{{{{ 
  {{{{ }}}}, 
  {{{{ 
    {{{{ }}}}, 
    {{{{ }}}} 
  }}}} 
}}}};
```

Honestly, using constructors look more readable

```
struct S {
    // this one is not really required by C++0x, but some GCC versions
    // require it.
    S(char const *s)
    :v(s) { } 

    S(std::string const& s)
    :v(s) { }

    S(std::initialize_list<S> s)
    :v(std::vector<S>(s)) { } 

    boost::variant<
      std::string,
      boost::recursive_wrapper<
        std::vector<
          S
        >
      >
    > v; 
};
```

Now it simplifies to

```
S s{ 
  "S1", 
  {
    "SS1",
    "SS2",
    { "SSS1", "SSS2" }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is an <strike>upcoming</strike>current feature of C++ called "initializer lists", where a vector or list can be initialized with = { }.
I don't know if they have come out with it in TR1 or not.  maybe it's in TR2.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    vector<int> vi = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    list<int> li = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    cout<<"vector size="<<vi.size()<<", list size="<<li.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the code you are using doesn't look proper to me.  If you want to implement structures that contain structures (a tree), include a list of pointers to the structures/nodes  (or just void pointers if that's not implementable) within the node.

most menu structures are essentially an ordered list-based tree (n nodes in one place, but could be m nodes elsewhere, etc).  Robert Sedgewick makes a textbook "Algorithms in C++".

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
void * pRoot = NULL; //pointer to CTree
class CTreenode;
class CTree;
class CTree {
    public:
        vector<class CTreeNode> lctnNodeList; //list does not have at() or operator[]
        vector<class CTreeNode>::iterator lctni;
    public:
        CTree() {}
        ~CTree() {
            for (lctni=lctnNodeList.begin(); lctni != lctnNodeList.end(); nctni++) {
                if (NULL==lctni->getChildPtr()) {
                    //do nothing, we have already done all we can
                } else {
                    delete (CTree *)lctnNodeList.pChild;
                }
                //do action here
            }
        }
        void addToList(string& data, CTree * p) { 
            CTreeNode ctn(data, p);
            lctnNodeList.push_back(d); 
        }
        void eraseAt(size_t index) { 
            vector<class CTreeNode>::iterator i = lctnNodeList.begin();
            vector<class CTreeNode>::iterator i2 = lctnNodeList.begin();
            i2++;
            size_t x;
            for (x=0; x <= index; x++,i++,i2++) {
                if (index == x) {
                    lctnNodeList.erase(i,i2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        void at(size_t index, string& returndata, CTree * &p) { 
            vector<class CTreeNode>::iterator i = lctnNodeList.begin();
            size_t x;
            for (x=0; x <= index; i++,x++) {
                if (x==index) {
                     i->getData(returndata, p);
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
        const CTreeNode& operator[](const size_t idx) {
            if (idx < lctnNodeList(size)) {
                return lctnNodeList.at(idx);
            } else {
                //throw an error
            }
        }
        const size() {
            return lctnNodeList.size();
        }
        //this can be applied to the root of the tree (pRoot).
        doActionToThisSubtree(void * root) {
            CTree * pct = (CTree *)root;
            for (pct->lctni=pct->lctnNodeList.begin(); pct->lctni != pct->lctnNodeList.end(); pct->nctni++) {
                //this is a depth-first traversal.
                if (NULL==pct->lctni->getChildPtr()) {
                    //do nothing, we have already done all we can
                    //we do this if statement to prevent infinite recursion
                } else {
                    //at this point, recursively entering child domain
                    doActionToThisSubtree(pct->lctni->getChildPtr());
                    //at thisd point, exiting child domain
                }
                //do Action on CTreeNode node pct->lctni-> here.
            }
        }
};
class CTreeNode {
    public:
        CTree * pChild; //CTree *, may have to replace with void *
        string sData;
    public:
        CTreeNode() : pChild(NULL) {}
        CTreeNode(string& data, pchild) : pChild(pchild) {
            sData = data;
        }
        ~CTreeNode() { 
             if (NULL!=pChild) { 
                 delete pChild;//delete (CTree *)pChild; 
                 pChild = NULL; 
             }
        void getChild(CTreeNode& child) { 
            child = *pChild;//child = *((CTree *)pChild); 
        }
        bool addChild(string& s) { 
            if (NULL==pChild) {
                return false;
            } else {
                pChild = new CTree;
            }
            return true;
        }
        void * getChildPtr() { return pChild; }
        void getData(string& data, CTree * &p) { //not sure about how to put the & in there on CTree
            data=sData;
            p = pChild;
        }
        void setData(string& data, CTree * p) {
            sData=data;
            pChild = p;
        }
};
```

the problem is mutual dependency here, and I think I have it resolved with the class declaration.
do class CTreeNode; before class CTree {}.
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=383253

I am probably mangling this code, and it's incomplete, because I haven't had the need to write a tree in years, but I think I've covered the basics.  I didn't implement operator[].

Comment: `std::initialize_list<>` is as much a language feature as library feature, and consequently cannot be part of a Technical Report (i.e., is part of C++0x only).