# Segfault with boost variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I've started to build up a little data type and at the current stage I have only one recursive type in a boost variant. It turns out, I get a segfault when I try to instantiate my type. If I put a string before the recursive type it works, putting it after the type it doesn't. I'm using mingw with gcc 4.8.1 64bit and boost 1.54.

Am I using boost variant the wrong way?

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A;
struct B;

using C = boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<A>>;

// works:
// using C = boost::variant<std::string, boost::recursive_wrapper<A>>;

struct A {
  std::string name;
  C variant;
};

struct B {
  std::string name;
  C variant;
};

int main() {

  std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
  B hAST; // <--- segfaults
  std::cout << "end" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you get is Stack Overflow :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is due to the "never-empty" guarantee of `variant`: The default constructor of `C` must initialize itself with a default-constructed value of its first template parameter - which is `recursive_wrapper<A>` - and the default constructor of `recursive_wrapper<A>` must initialize itself with a default-constructed instance of `A`, which leads to infinite recursion.

Assuming you actually want a `variant` that is either empty, or an instance of `A`, you could introduce a dummy type as the variant's first parameter, for example:

```
struct variant_is_empty { };

using C = boost::variant<variant_is_empty, boost::recursive_wrapper<A>>;
```

---

EDIT: [It appears you can use `boost::recursive_wrapper` with `boost::optional`,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694276/231299) which would be easier than using `variant` for the above case of an optional, recursive type.