# C++ building a double sided Tree with operator overloading - what is good memory solution?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

So following this question I asked before: [C++ return by value - what happens with the pointer inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189033/c-return-by-value-what-happens-with-the-pointer-inside/29189426#29189426) 
I was wondering if further I impose that the parents have to have a list of pointer to their children, is there any good solution, in terms of not having any memory leaks with shared and weak pointers in any way, since I will need to dynamically allocate memory inside the body of the operator.  You can assume that the compute graph is acyclic.

Specifically consider my.h:

```
class Interface{
public:
    int myid();
    Interface(double in);
    ~Interface(){
            std::cout<<"Destroy "<<myid()<<std::endl;
     }
    friend Interface operator+(const Interface& a, const Interface& b);
    void tree();
private:
    class Impl;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pimpl;
};
Interface operator+(const Interface& a, const Interface& b);
```

And the my.cpp:

```
class autodiff::Interface::Impl{
public:
    static int id;
    int myid;
    double value;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<autodiff::Interface::Impl>> children;
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<autodiff::Interface::Impl>> parents;
    Impl(double val) : value(val), myid(++id){};
    ~Impl(){
        std::cout<<"Destroy: "<<myid<<std::endl;
        for(auto it:children)
            it.reset();
    }
    void tree();

};

autodiff::Interface::Interface(double in){
    pimpl = std::make_shared<Impl>(in);
}

int autodiff::Interface::myid() {
    return pimpl->myid;
}

autodiff::Interface& autodiff::operator+(const Interface &a, const Interface &b) {
    Interface* ch = new Interface(a.pimpl->value + b.pimpl->value);
    a.pimpl->children.push_back(ch->pimpl);
    b.pimpl->children.push_back(ch->pimpl);
    ch->pimpl->parents.push_back(a.pimpl);
    ch->pimpl->parents.push_back(b.pimpl);
    return *ch;
}
void autodiff::Interface::tree() {
    pimpl->tree();
}
void autodiff::Interface::Impl::tree() {
    std::cout<<myid<<"-(";
    for(int i=0;i<parents.size();i++)
        if(auto tmp = parents[i].lock())
            std::cout<<tmp->myid<<",";
    std::cout<<")"<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<parents.size();i++)
        if(auto tmp = parents[i].lock())
            tmp->tree();
}

int autodiff::Interface::Impl::id = 0;
```

The output is:

```
5-(4,3,)
4-(1,2,)
1-()
2-()
3-()
Destroy: 3
Destroy: 2
Destroy: 1
```

Where what I want and expect was:

```
5-(4,3,)
4-(1,2,)
1-()
2-()
3-()
Destroy 3
Destroy 2
Destroy 1
Destroy 5
Destroy 4
```

My question is why aren't the temporary created objects 4 and 5 get freed automatically? After 1,2,3 are destroyed there could be only weak_ptr to those instance and no shared_ptr or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your previous question, but when I was once writing a binary tree implementation, I found it convenient to use `std::unique_ptr` to the children nodes and a simple observing raw pointer to the parent node, i.e. something like

```
struct Node
{
    Node *parent;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
};
```

All these should be initialized to `std::nullptr`. With this, the whole subtree below `left` or `right` is correctly destructed once `Node` is destructed, so there is no need to do this recursively. "Observing pointer" to the parent node means you should never do some memory-related action with it, particularly no delete.

Comment: So in my case, a child can have more than 1 parent, and I'm overloading the operator+ such that it takes two instances of class Node and creates a new one and returns it. Now this means that I must return by reference not by value from operator+ because of expressions like a+b+c, where there is a temporary object. In terms this means that with raw pointers the temporary node won't be cleaned.

Comment: @Belov: yes, my answer refers to the special case of a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29). For a general acyclic graph, you can switch to a `shared_ptr`-to-the-children / `weak_ptr`-to-the-parent implementation.

Comment: it sounds like you want to returns a unique_ptr<> from operator+ then

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work, only thing left is how do get inside an operator+ overloading from a Reference(Node& p1) to make a weak poitner? do you know?

Comment: @Arvid: I have no idea what `operator+` shall do here, and before that I wouldn't want to give any advice. Moreover, in general I don't even know what `operator+` *should* do for two nodes, so I wouldn't use it at all.

Comment: yeah, after posting that I realized it's not clear at all what should happen. I was sort of imagining taking two unique_ptr<> to subtrees and moving them into the new parent node and returning that. It makes for an unusual operator+ for sure.

Comment: @Belov: without knowing deeper exactly what you're looking for. If your nodes derive from std::enable_shared_from_this<Node>, you can ask shared_from_this() which you can make a weak pointer from. It might very well be the case that shared_ptr<> and weak_ptr<> is the right tool for you, keep in mind though that you allow cycles if you're not careful.

Comment: Could you look at the link I post, it contains code which roughly explains what I want, without the extra thing of having pointers from parents->children. I didn't want to copy the whole question, in short I need a wrapper around a numeric class and to overload operators.